# Senryū 川柳 is it Sino-Japanese or Yamato

Tags: etymology

Senryū 川柳 is it Sino-Japanese or Yamato

Answer (score 1):

川柳 is read as せんりゅう, and both せん and りゅう are on-yomi. In this sense, this is close to Sino-Japanese. (川柳 would be かわやなぎ if read with kun-yomi.)

But 川柳 is named after a Japanese poet 柄井川柳 (Karai Senryū) in the 18th century (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senry%C5%AB)). So I think it's difficult to classify this word as a typical Sino-Japanese term.